# How to access Public Folder in Windows 8.1?

Tags: xamarin, windows-8.1

We are developing an app for Windows 8.1 (Windows Store App), our scenario is to support Public folder access from Windows App by various Windows users.

As per our requirement in tablet we need to create SQLite DB which should be common for various windows users in the same tablet. Please find below the system environment

1. Windows 10 Tablet (App Tageting from Windows 8.1)
2. Domain Users login support
3. Our app be installed for all users access

Appreciate if any one suggests solution for this scenario.

Comment: I understand this is not exactly a coding question and there's not much concrete stuff that you can post. But in my opinion the question as you've formulated is quite broad. Please take a look to [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). I would suggest you at least add the stuff you've already investigated, the decisions that you may have taken already, so that maybe you can narrow your question somewhat. That way I'd say you'll get more chances for a good answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems what you are looking for is [`ApplicationData.SharedLocalFolder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.sharedlocalfolder.aspx). You can use that to store files sharable between users.

```
var folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.SharedLocalFolder;

var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("file.txt", 
   CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, "Hello, World!");
```